# Stack Overflowより新年の挨拶

Tags: 討議

[image: あけましておめでとうございます]

あけましておめでとうございます！

おかげさまで2014年12月の1ヶ月間で：

- 約500件の質問
- 約1000件の回答
- 約5000人のユーザー
- 約10万の閲覧回数

2015年も宜しくお願い致します。  
本年も皆さんと共にプログラミングの課題を解決しましょう。